# parse parameters in python in a line

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file which has some lines of:

```
FS "name" machine:"path"
{
}
```

which I want to read whatever comes after FS and return each parameter. I mean return should be name, machine and path.

```
Name:
    "/PF/B/"
    "/PF/A/"

Machine:
    FFFFFF..
    XXXXXX…

Path:
    “/PF/J”
    “/PF/K”
```

The code:

```
Def parse()
with open (myfile.txt) as f:
    for line in f:
if line.strip().startswith(‘FS’)
            Name = []
            Machine = []
            Path = []
????
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You might use a regular expression,

```
import re
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    found = re.findall(r'^FS\s*"([^"]*)"\s*([^:]*)\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"',f.read(),re.MULTILINE)
names, machines, paths = zip(*found)
```

EDIT : check if 'FS' is at the beginning of a line

EDIT2 : works with possible spaces between search patterns

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression to match those lines, storing the results as I go:

```
import re

results = []
with open ('myfile.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    match = re.match(r'FS\s+(".*?")\s+(.*?):(".*?")', line)
    if match:
      results.append(match.groups())

if results:
  print 'Name:\n' + '\n'.join('    '+result[0] for result in results)
  print 'Machine:\n' + '\n'.join('    '+result[1] for result in results)
  print 'Path:\n' + '\n'.join('    '+result[2] for result in results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the re module:

```
line = "FS "name" machine:"path""
for n in re.split(" ", line)
    print(n)
```

Will print:

FS

"name"

machine

"path"

**EDIT:** sorry the last one would print machine:"path" and then you'll have to do re.split(":", n) and then it will print machine and then "path"

Comment: So long as neither name, machine, nor path ever contain spaces.  The other answers are a lot more robust.

Comment: you said that how your file looks like so I gave you an answer according to that, if you want a more robust answer give a more accurate description...